# Find receipt on device for inapp purchase on sandbox works fine but not on production

Tags: ios, objective-c, in-app-purchase

To validate if the user has purchased my premium version I check if there is a receipt on the device. We tested on the sandbox environment where the following code works fine. Removing the app from the device, testing on the sandbox environment through test flight worked as expected.

```
NSURL *receiptURL = [[NSBundle mainBundle] appStoreReceiptURL];

NSError *receiptError;
BOOL isPresent = [receiptURL checkResourceIsReachableAndReturnError:&receiptError];
if (isPresent) {
    NSData *receiptData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:receiptURL];
    if (receiptData) {
        NSLog(@"[checkReceiptURL]Valid receipt on device...");
```

On production it seems that the above code is always finding a receipt on the device what is not consistent with the sandbox environment and documentation. I checked the console output of the production version and its output is that it finds a receipt.

Anybody having the same experience? What is it I'm missing here?

Comment: Are you saying that you _are_ finding a receipt in production, but that the receipt looks different? Or are you saying that on production your are _not_finding the receipt at all with this code?

Comment: hi Ben, in production I do find a receipt. During sandbox testing there was no receipt at all until the inapp purchase. The only testing I did to check if the purchase took place during the app start was just to check if there was a receipt in my bundle.

Comment: Ok. That is expected (if unfortunate) behavior. In production you get a receipt for the app itself. In sandbox you have to manually refresh the receipt after an install (which can trigger a password prompt) or perform an IAP before you get one. The production app receipt could be useful event without IAPs if you had transitioned a paid app into an unlockable one and you wanted to check the original app version on the receipt.